# Print Rdlc report without showing preview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I made a project to print an invoice but I'm trying to print my report without showing print preview in reportviewer, can anyone help me?
Here is my code I used it to print:

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet1
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)

    If Cn.State = 1 Then Cn.Close()
    If Rs.State = 1 Then Rs.Close()
    Cn.Open(constr)
    Rs.Open("Select * From tbltemp", Cn, 1, 2)
    For x = 0 To Rs.RecordCount - 1
        Dim r As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        r("itemcode") = Rs.Fields("itemcode").Value
        r("itemname") = Rs.Fields("itemname").Value
        r("itemunit") = Rs.Fields("itemunit").Value
        r("itemsize") = Rs.Fields("itemsize").Value
        r("itemqnt") = Rs.Fields("itemqnt").Value
        r("reqdate") = Format(Rs.Fields("reqdate").Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        r("ava1") = Rs.Fields("ava1").Value
        r("ava2") = Rs.Fields("ava2").Value
        r("rejust") = Rs.Fields("rejust").Value
        Rs.MoveNext()
        dt.Rows.Add(r)
    Next
    Rs.MoveFirst()

    frmreport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    frmreport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New   ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables(0)))      frmreport.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
    frmreport.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

     Cn.Close()
     frmreport.Show()
```

Comment: I found [this in a google search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx) a while back but I've never take the time to work through it.

Comment: thanx @Charles May, i read this before but no solution comes on!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print rdlc report without viewing print dialogue box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011576/print-rdlc-report-without-viewing-print-dialogue-box)

Comment: i read that solution before, but i can't get the point of it and transform it to my project!

Comment: Here is more material: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx You just need to work through it.